# Bayesian Survival Analysis - COX PHD Time Varying Covariates Implementation

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, python, survival

Suppose you are interested in the Survival modelling technique Cox Proportional Hazard, where we model the hazard as:

$$ \lambda(t \vert x) = \lambda_0(t) exp (\beta x)  $$

An extension of this model is **time-varying covariates** i.e.

$$ \lambda(t \vert x(t)) = \lambda_0(t) exp (\beta  x(t))  $$

Another extension is **time-dependent effects** i.e.:

$$ \lambda(t \vert x) = \lambda_0(t) exp (\beta(t)x)  $$

I am interested in **time-varying covariates** and have strong prior beliefs over the coefficients of the covariates (in the partial hazard) as well as the baseline. I have seen examples of Bayesian survival modelling (with Cox PHD) where you have **time-dependent effects** (i.e. a sequence of regression coefficients), see [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20201113230220/https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/survival_analysis.html) using PyMC3 and Python:

However, in the situation where you have **time varying covariates**, I am yet to find an example or implementation of this in python (or R for that matter). My question is:

1. Is there a reason why you do not see implementations of Bayesian time-varying covariates COX PHD?
2. If no to the above, does anyone have a good example of an implementation?

Many thanks

Comment: How many distinct event times are there in your data?  If you happen to have a discrete time problem this is easier to handle.

Answer (score 3):

If you get the development version of **rstanarm** package, it has function called **stan_surv** that allows for time-varying coefficients in Bayesian survival models. Importantly, you can even model flexible baseline hazards with M and B splines. You can find out more here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.09633.pdf

https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm

Comment: Thanks Brant. Do you know if this covers time varying covariates as well as time varying coefficients?

Comment: Seems to does...do you also happen to know if the python implementation Survivalstan has the same features developed as the R implementation with stan_surv?

Comment: Sorry I don't use Python and have no idea.